# Vlookup between sheets

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two worksheets in a workbook. In the first I have column a with 1, 2, 3 ,4 in each row respectfully. In the second sheet I have 6,7,1,8 in column A and a,b,c,d in column B. I am trying to use Vlookup in sheet1 column b to compare coulmn A sheet 1 with column A sheet 2, if they match column B sheet A should be set to the same value as column B sheet 2.

This is what I have tried but it just returns #REF:

=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A1,2,FALSE)

Do you know what I need to change?

Comment: You're missing a lookup range, you're just searching for `A1` in `Sheet2!A1` only - do you mean perhaps `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A1:B100,2,FALSE)`?

Comment: Thanks, what would you do if the coulmns were not next to each other. Say column D instead of B?

Comment: Then try `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A1:D100,4,FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below formula

=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4,2,0)

You missed the range after"Sheet2" and After adding the range make sure you lock the lookup cells using $ as in the formula. Hope this helps.